# Getting the value of last row, last column of a table which has dynamic number of columns

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table which shows my report results, it has 4 rows and the number of rows are fixed, but the number of column changes according to the begin and end year that I am setting for my report. I need to get the value in the last row, last column cell in my table. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

if you have jquery in hand is very simple just

```
$('table tr:last-child td:last-child)
```

should give you the last col in the last row of every table

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `querySelector()` :

```
var val = document.querySelector('table tr:last-child td:last-child').innerHTML
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Vs77a/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
var table = document.getElementById('tableID');
var num = table.rows[3].cells.length
var x = table.rows[3].cells[num - 1].innerHTML;
```

[JSfiddle for test](http://jsfiddle.net/ag84M/)